# How to add nested child div using JSON and a recursive function . .?

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, reddit

I am using the Reddit api to recursively get the comments and replies and I cannot for the life of me figure out a clean way to indent each reply to the parent div if and only if it's parent is the comment the reply is for. How should I go about doing this . .?

```
function reddit(){
    var url = "https://www.reddit.com/r/news/comments/5959v5/exceo_of_red_light_camera_firm_sentenced_to_14/.json";
    var promise = $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function(json_data) {
        $("#content").text("");//replace #content text with empty string
        var comments = commentsFromJSON(json_data[1].data.children);
        comments = $.parseHTML( comments );
        comments = $("<div />").html(comments).text();
        $("#content").append(comments);
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("geddit Error");
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });
}

function commentsFromJSON(arr) {
    var comments = '';

    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (typeof arr[i] !== 'undefined') {
            comments += arr[i].data.body_html;

            if (typeof arr[i].data.replies !== 'undefined' && arr[i].data.replies !== '') {
                comments += commentsFromJSON(arr[i].data.replies.data.children);
            }
        }
    }
    return comments;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jq9wwszz/

But I am not currently appending any divs, just appending a parsed HTML string at the end. I guess where I am having trouble is how I can use the iteration index position to then check if it is > 0 it should be a reply to the previous parent div.